# Append Ionic Tags from ts file to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to add a div on the HTML file in my ionic app. I have created new Div and append it to the primary div in the HTML file using `.innerHTML` but the ionic tags are not being applied.

**MY html file**

```
 <div class="vehicle-profile" id="vehicle-profile" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="upload">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-2>
              <div class="upload-small" (tap)="scanBarcode(i)">
                <img src="assets/icon/barcode.png" width="50px">
                <p style="margin: 0"> SCAN</p>
              </div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col offset-1 col-9>
              <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="VIN #" [(ngModel)]="vin[i]"  name="vin_number[{{i}}]" (ngModelChange)="getVehicleInfo($event, i)">
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6>
                <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Year" [(ngModel)]="year[i]" name="year[{{i}}]">
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6>
                <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Make"  [(ngModel)]="make[i]"  name="make[{{i}}]">
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-12>
                <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Model" [(ngModel)]="model[i]"  name="model[{{i}}]">
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6>
                <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Plate #" [(ngModel)]="plate_num[i]" name="plat_number[{{i}}]">
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6>
                <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Mileage" [(ngModel)]="mileage[i]" name="mileage[{{i}}]">
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col offset-4 col-4>
                <div class="delete-btn" >
                    <button type="button" ion-button block large (click)="removeVehicleBox(i)">
                      <p class="{{i}}">
                          Delete Profile
                      </p>
                    </button>
                  </div>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </div>
</div>
```

when i append the same from the .ts file, it wont show the css effect.

**TS file**

```
 addVehicleBox(){
    this.num = this.num+1;
    var content = document.createElement('div');      
    content.innerHTML = this.uploadBoxForm(this.num);
    document.getElementById('vehicle-profile').appendChild(content);
  }

  removeVehicleBox(selectedBox){
    console.log(selectedBox)
  }

  uploadBoxForm(i){
    let data = `
    <div class="upload">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-2>
          <div class="upload-small" (tap)="scanBarcode(`+i+`)">
            <img src="assets/icon/barcode.png" width="50px">
            <p style="margin: 0"> SCAN</p>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col offset-1 col-9>
          <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="VIN #" [(ngModel)]="vin[`+i+`]"  name="vin_number[`+i+`]" (ngModelChange)="getVehicleInfo($event, i)">
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Year" [(ngModel)]="year[`+i+`]" name="year[`+i+`]">
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Make"  [(ngModel)]="make[`+i+`]"  name="make[`+i+`]">
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-12>
            <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Model" [(ngModel)]="model[`+i+`]"  name="model[`+i+`]">
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Plate #" [(ngModel)]="plate_num[`+i+`]" name="plat_number[`+i+`]">
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <input type="text" class="formfield" placeholder="Mileage" [(ngModel)]="mileage[`+i+`]" name="mileage[`+i+`]">
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col offset-4 col-4>
            <div class="delete-btn" >
                <button type="button" ion-button block large (click)="removeVehicleBox(`+i+`)">
                  <p class="{{i}}">
                      Delete Profile
                  </p>
                </button>
              </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
    `
    return data;
  }
```

Here, i have attached the image Showing the effect of using the ion tags in inner html from ts file. 1 is the ion tags written in html file and 2 is the appended ion tags from ts file.
[image].

Is there anyway that i could render the ion tags ?

Comment: You can not use non-standard web components dynamically like you are trying to. This won;t work with ionic and angular etc components as they need to get "bootstrapped" etc. You can do that with standard components and then "style" them to look like ionic. If you really want to achieve what you have here think about leveraging Ionic's Segment etc approaches.

Comment: so you mean i have to make a component and call them?

Comment: Yes so basically when you have a component with all that Angular/ionic specific markup - that is not what is going to be eventually there in your browser, right? Angular will bootstrap/interpret all that jazz into relevant standard web elements with tons of styling etc. So Ideally you should create a normal component for the detail form that you have. There is actually a way to do dynamic components: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: but based on your needs I think you could getaway with just having Segment https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/ that ngSwitches to relevant required template

Comment: i don't think segments can be used. I need to add the box with the forms or delete them dynamically. I also need to save all the forms value. So would a component work for this?

Comment: Yes components should work. If you can add you implementation and outline what you struggle with - happy to help!

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you are adding the css classes and code?
I see your second example without

```
"style="padding-bottom: 10px;"
```

Could be you are missing css styles in your

```
var content = document.createElement('div');
```

?

Comment: the style is for the parent div and i am appending the child to that div. and as you can see in the image, i have applied CSS and its working, its just ionic default styles are not being used